# Asterisk module development

Tags: asterisk

I am planing to develop application module for asterisk and want to put it on asterisk digium source tree, so it will be available in next release of asterisk.

But I am confuse about which asterisk version should I use,

Asterisk 15 Standard
Asterisk 14 Standard
Certified Asterisk 13
Asterisk 13 LTS

Help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

New module for sure will not go certified tree.

You have do fork of latest TRUNK version

0) ensure your module is needed at least someone except you. Module which needed only for your organization will NOT be merged.

1) check your module with new trunk code

2) ensure it writted accordinly to guidlines

3) ensure it not broke anything

4) ensure you can compile it under main architectures(32bit,64bit, ARM64 etc)

5) write email to someone from core team with review&merge request.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I understand your points. But I am confuse about which version of asterisk trunk (latest) should be used... Asterisk 13, 14 or 15. Asterisk 14, 15 are standard support so no will be long time available for issue etc while Asterisk 13 is LTS. so should I use Asterisk 13 or Asterisk 15.

Comment: You should read about SVN. New modules will be accepted only for TRUNK(top edge version).

Answer (score 0):

The policy for feature-inclusion in branches is outlined here:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Software+Configuration+Management+Policies#SoftwareConfigurationManagementPolicies-FeaturePolicy

13 and 15 are eligible to receive new features, provided that those features have suitable test coverage.  A new feature that goes into 13 won't typically find its way into an existing 13-cert release, as Digium maintains those branches separately.  But, as 13 moves forward and new -cert releases are made from the main 13 branch, those new releases would inherit the features from mainline 13.

14 is no longer receiving new features, or bug fixes for that matter, per:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Versions